# The keyboard knocks down the state of the bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, state, textfield, bloc

I have a problem that if the keyboard is open, the state of the bloc is lost.
What do I mean:

1. enter the data in the field
2. do not close the keyboard
3. press the button that triggers the bloc event
4. the keyboard hides and overlaps the event with the base state (Initial)
   [image]

```
BlocConsumer<UserBloc, UserState>(
                  bloc: bloc,
                  listener: (context, state) {
                        if (state is AuthorizatedState) {
                          // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()));
                          // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()));
                        }
                          print("[Login] state is change on $state");
                      },
                      builder: (context, state) {
                          print("[Login] state in builder: $state");
                         return Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Авторизация', style: TextStyles.h1(color: ProjectColors.darkBlue),),
                        const SizedBox(height: 30,),
                        if (state is UserInitialState)
                          CustomInputField('Логин', loginController,),
                        if (state is UserInitialState)
                          CustomInputField('Пароль', passwordController,),

                        if (state is AuthorizatedState)
                          CustomInputField('Логин', loginController, errorText: 'Неправильный логин', errorActive: !state.authorizated),
                        if (state is AuthorizatedState)
                          CustomInputField('Пароль', passwordController, errorText: 'Неправильный пароль',  errorActive: !state.authorizated),
                        if (state is LoadingState)
                          const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),
                        if (state is AuthorizatedState || state is AuthentificatedState || state is ErrorState || state is UserInitialState)
                          Column(children: [
                            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Забыли пароль?', style: TextStyles.text(color: ProjectColors.darkBlue),)),
                            const SizedBox(height: 30,),
                            UniversalButton(context,
                            colorButton: ProjectColors.darkBlue, filled: false, text: 'Войти', textStyle: TextStyles.text(),
                            onTap: () async {
                              print("[Login] loggin");
                              // FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                              // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
                              bloc.add(AuthorizationEvent(loginController.text, passwordController.text));
                            }),
                            const SizedBox(height: 15,),
                            UniversalButton(context,
                            colorButton: ProjectColors.darkBlue, text: 'Регистрация', textStyle: TextStyles.text(color: Colors.white),
                            onTap: () {
                              print("go to reg");
                              setState(() {
                                modeIsLogin = false;
                              });
                              // pageControllerBloc.add(AuthorizationControllerOpenRegistrationEvent());
                            }),
                          ],)
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                )
```

I can't figure out how I can make sure that the keyboard doesn't bring down the state of the bloc.

I tried unfocusing, but it didn't help. I also tried to make a delay, but then I realized that it was pointless.
I am only studying the bloc, so I may not know what I need.